# Timeout a long running SQL Server query in a java application running inside tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, timeout

I have a java web app that is running inside tomcat and the application has a page (JSP) where users clicks (some buttons on that web page) which results in hitting a query behind the page and reloads it with new information and sometimes that query takes longer than expected and I want to kill the query automatically if it runs longer than x minutes. How can I achieve that at tomcat side, is that even possible with any tomcat server configurations like timeout or anything, if so could someone please guide me or show an example configuration or setting change I can try? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`Statement.setQueryTimeout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout-int-) which is a feature of JDBC, not of any specific application server, etc. You will want to call that method and set an appropriate timeout. Your queries will throw `SQLTimeoutException` if the timeout elapses and your application will have to decide what to do next.